# Updating VRT raster layers in QGIS 3.28.3 (Windows) with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, gdal, qgis-3, vrt

I'm trying to update a VRT raster layer in QGIS after clipping the VRT file with Python GDAL. When I pan with the mouse afterwards, I lose my raster and get the following GDAL warning for all raster bands:

```
MyRaster : C:/Data/MyRaster.vrt, band 1: Access window out of range in RasterIO(). Requested (0,0) of size 2481x1754 on raster of 1028x1223.
```

To refresh the affected raster layer, I use a custom Python function:

```py
def refreshLayer(self, layerSrc):
    for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
        if layer.type() == QgsMapLayerType.RasterLayer and layer.publicSource().lower() == layerSrc.lower():
            # create temporary layer to force QGIS adding statistics to the new VRT file
            tempLayer =  QgsRasterLayer(layerSrc,"temp", 'gdal')

            newDatasource = tempLayer.source()
            QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayers([tempLayer.id()])
            
            layer.setDataSource(newDatasource,layer.name(),'gdal')
```

The following Python lines, which are called after refreshing the layer, don't help here either:

```
layer.reload()
self.iface.actionDraw().trigger()
self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

When I refresh QGIS map canvas with the <kbd>F5</kbd> key pressed after updating my layer, there's no GDAL warning and everything is fine.

I even tried to run the QGIS "Refresh" action, unfortunately without luck:

```py
refresh = self.iface.mainWindow().findChild(QAction,'mActionDraw')
if refresh:
    refresh.trigger()
```

What can I do to prevent the GDAL warnings after refreshing the updated VRT raster layers? (Does QGIS automatically clean the rendering cache when we refresh map canvas with <kbd>F5</kbd> key?)

Comment: Can you load the clipped VRT in a new QGIS project without issues?

Comment: @bugmenot123 yes, the VRT is perfectly valid. As I wrote before, pressing F5 after refreshing the layer helps. The question is: how can I simulate pressing F5 without getting a GDAL warning?

Comment: Sorry, I skipped that part, seemed like an obvious question I did not see. Your `refreshLayer` method looks very complex and is calling into really deep parts of the API. Can't you use [setDataSource](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsMapLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsMapLayer.setDataSource())?

Comment: I tried `setDataSource` as well, but without any change.

Comment: No change meaning the same behaviour or nothing happening? If it behaves the same, best update the question and discard your code :D

Comment: @bugmenot123 when using `setDataSource` to refresh the raster layer, I get the GDAL warnings as well. My refresh code is borrowed from `changeDataSource` plugin, but maybe it's only useful with vector layers, I don't know... I guess my `refreshLayer` function is not the problem here, but I will update the code, so that people are not getting confused.